# Is it safe to say that this set of data is constant with x because of their standard deviation?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, standard-error

[image: X,Y]
Is it safe to say that Y does not change with X because if you take the mean of Y and calculate the standard deviation all of the values fall with 1 standard deviation ?

Comment: Plot the (x,y) values.  Add error bars if you like.  What does it tell you?

Comment: I have, this study is to examine if the Y values change with x in any way even if its pseudorandom, the question is that the points do differ with x but the difference between them is within one standard deviation of the mean of Y so is it safe to say that they don't change with x ?